# Why do variables in mathematics always represent properties of objects?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

When I read about mathematical modelling, a variable is always used to represent a property of an object, for example the mass of an object.

"let m be a real number that represents the mass of an object."
"let p be a real number that represent the number of people in a population."

Why do the variables always represent a property/quantity?

Comment: I do not agree that variables always represent properties of objects. Variables can also represent objects themselves: Denote by EVEN the set of even numbers and by ODD the set of odd numbers. Then the cardinality of EVEN equals the cardinality of ODD.

Comment: Are you trying to get to the most basic level of applying math to the real world, such as f=ma? force, mass, acceleration being real numbers. Is that mathematical modeling for this question? Even modeling rabbit populations with Fibonacci numbers, all the way to docking in space? As in, how does applied math work at all? Or is it more general extending to properties of pure math, like how often are there prime numbers?

Comment: "When I read about mathematical __modelling__ ....". Because you're __modelling__ something.

Comment: On the contrary, when quantifiers bind variables, the variables are for "objects" rather than "properties" (often enough, though we can "objectify" a property as a second-order object, for what it's worth).

Comment: thank you so much for the help, am I right in thinking that the instances of the variable represent instances of the represented object set? so given "a: Real" where a represents an age, instances of that age are represented by instances of a?